# Is there any way to include # in the CSV input without breaking the format

Tags: javascript, csv, special-characters, hashtag, html-escape-characters

In my project I am trying to create CSV report by converting a JSON to comma seperated values enclosed with double quotes. But while in the JSON I have # as a value in some places.
So while downloading CSV report i am getting the only contents which are present before #. But I need to show # in my CSV report. Help me to solve this in Js.`enter code here`

Tried the escape sequence for # '#' still it is not working

The real JSON is like this

```
    "details": [{
    "name": "def",
    "number": "123#456",
    "class": "one"
},
{
    "name": "ab",
    "number": "123#456",
    "class": "two"
}]
```

and I am appending these values with "" like

```
row+=`"${details.name}"`..
```

So expected output should be
name number class
def 123#456 one
ab 23#456 two

But the output is
name number class
def  123

Nothing is printing after starting from '#' –

Comment: CSV format doesn't have any specific issues with hash symbols. As long as your values are properly enclosed in double quotes, special characters like `#` should be preserved without issue.

Consider trying {name: "apple#233"}

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the tool that's loading the CSV file, it seems like it's treating it as a comment character. But there's no commenting in CSV.

Comment: Note, neither `{name :apple#233}` nor `{name:"apple#233"}` are *valid* JSON.  It should be `{"name":"apple#233"}`  (maybe it is, but that's not what's provided in the question/comments.

Comment: Are you sure it's an issue with the CSV *reader*?  Why not confirm that the CSV has been generated correctly by loading it into a text editor?   Can you provide an example of the input and corresponding output?   If it's not in the CSV output, then it's your converter.

Comment: *I have mentioned that JSON for example* A) it's not valid JSON, B) there's no equivalent CSV line shown.   The way you've written the question, it does look like it's the generator that's not working.  Perhaps you could include that code if you want us to look at it...

Comment: Worth reading: [What is JSON and what is it used for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: @freedomn-m I have mentioned that JSON for example the real JSON is like this   "details":[{"name":"anand",
  "number":"123#456",
   "class":"one"
},
{"name":"ashok",
  "number":"123#456",
   "class":"two"
}
....
]

@BLAKE and Iam appending these values with "" like 

row += `"${details[i].name}",` 
row += `"${details[i].number}",` 
row += `"${details[i].class}",` 
..........


So expected output should be 
name   number   class
anand  123#456  one
ashok  123#456  two

But the out put is 
name   number   class
anand  123

Nothing is printing after starting from '#'

Comment: The generator file:

{
        const uri = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,\uFEFF${encodeURI(CSV)}`;
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = uri;
        link.style = 'visibility: hidden';
        link.download = `${fileName}.csv`;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
      }

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66767270/export-csv-data-with-character-in-javascript-does-not-work

Comment: The relevant part is `link.href = uri` - which I would 100% never had guessed that you were using from your description!   Copy and paste into your browser console: 
`encodeURI("abc#123")`  nothing to do with json, nothing to do with a CVS, all to do with putting it as a data: link.  Use `encodeURIComponent`.  Perhaps @Barmar could close as  duplicate for us?